# Ruby: Cryptographically sign a string to ensure authenticity?

Tags: ruby, encryption, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

Lets say I have a origin server which through the act of a redirect with particular query string params needs to provide details to a target server. However, I need to ensure those details came from my origin server only.

Also I can't sure the integrity of the target server. Or specifically, the target server might be compromised so any encryption keys might have been read by a malicious party.

I'm thinking I could sign the query string using some form of public/private keypair. The origin server uses a private key to sign the string, and the target server uses a public key to verify it came from my origin server, and the message hasn't been tampered with.

I'm far from a cryptography expert or anything, so any assumption here I've made might be wrong, please correct me if so :)

I'm basically after a (hopefully) simple way to do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the easiest form of signing the query data (in your case a redirection URL) is by using an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). Your origin and destination server would need to share a common key in this case - HMACs are not a form of public/private key cryptography, but rather a form of keyed hashing.

The module you're looking for is [ruby-hmac](http://ruby-hmac.rubyforge.org/), and your source and destination server would have to do something like:

```
require 'hmac-md5'
HMAC::MD5.new("<your shared key>").update("<your URL to check>").hexdigest
```

and compare on the destination side that the digest computed by the HMAC on the source side is equivalent: both sides thus do the same computation. The hexdigest of the HMAC can simply be transported by an additional query parameter from source to destination.

Comment: That's interesting, but I had hoped to be able not have to share the exact same key between the origin and target server. Basically I only have physical access to the origin server, the target server is hosted by a third party. It's a low change right now, but further down the line the target server could be compromised and any encryption keys on it used by a malicious party. I could use a unique HMAC key for each target server, but would like to avoid it as it adds complexity :)

Comment: You could derive a host-specific HMAC-key using an HMAC: thus, on your source side, the calculation becomes: `HMAC::MD5.new(HMAC::MD5.new("<your secret key>").update("<hostname>").hexdigest).update("<your URL to check>").hexdigest`, and you give `HMAC::MD5.new("<your secret key>").update("<hostname>").hexdigest` to the remote party as their secret key. This is probably easier than setting up public/private key cryptography - and don't forget that public/private-key cryptography signatures are a lot of data to be transferred between the systems.

Comment: [MD5 is broken](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068) and should no longer be used (or recommended) for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: For my recommendation it is irrelevant that MD5 is no longer considered collision-resistant: using HMAC (which relies on a _secret_ key to derive the hash) means that an attacker, even though he can produce hash collisions on the basic MD5-function, cannot create new HMAC signatures without knowing the secret key, as that influences how the hash function operates internally (and thus thwarts collision attempts). Of course, the OP may resort to HMAC-SHA256 or some other hash of the SHA2-family if it makes him feel better, but that also means that the data transferred for the sig is larger.